# Не работает код js+html

Tags: javascript

Необходимо, чтобы в js-окно alert выводилось содержимое элемента html-списка. Но, представленный ниже код не работает. Подскажите, плиз, ошибки:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">                 
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function Click(evt) {
        alert(evt.target.ownerDocument.getElementByTagName('li').innerHTML);
      {  
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul> 
      <li onclick = "Click(evt);">Первый</li> 
      <li onclick = "Click(evt);">Второй</li> 
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Ну начнем с того,что скобка закрытия функции Click стоит в обратную сторону.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function Click(obj) { 
    alert(obj.innerHTML); 
}
</script>
</head> 
<body>
<ul> 
    <li onclick = "Click(this);">Первый</li> 
    <li onclick = "Click(this);">Второй</li> 
</ul> 
</body> 
</html>
```

вот так будет работать.

Answer (score 0):

1. Тело функции не закрыто, а открыто еще раз.
2. В функцию вы пытаетесь передать событие, а реально передается элемент.
3. `evt.target.ownerDocument` - лютый ....
4. getElementByTagName() - нет такой функции. Есть getElementsByTagName().
5. Но она возвращает nodelist, а не один элемент, поэтому взять его innerHTML не получится.
6. Вы лезете в дебри языка, не прочитав основ.

Answer (score 0):

Не правильно обращаться getElementByTagName! Правильно - getElementsByTagName! Elements - поскольку элементов много, не сравнивайте с getElementById - здесь элемент (Element) только 1
И потом, getElementsByTagName('li')[0] - вернёт первый li, [1] - второй и т.д.